# disable receive push from didReceive in NotificationService

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, swift4

I want to disable send push notification to user under special conditions. 
I saved my first Push in userDefault and in the second I check if it's the same. 
when i debug it enter to return and not continue, but still i get a push notification. the push sent from firebase  api

```
 override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

    if let dict = request.content.userInfo["aps"] as? Dictionary<AnyHashable, AnyHashable> {
        if let did = dict["did"] as? String {
            if let message = dict["message"] as? String {
                let currentPush = did + "_" + message

                if let lastPush = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "lastPush"), currentPush == lastPush {
                    print("enter")
                    return
                }
                else {
                    UserDefaults.standard.setValue(currentPush, forKey: "lastPush")
                }
            }
        }
    }}
```

Comment: This is the service's decision to send Push or not. You could call a web API to tell services that I don't want to receive a certain push anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Android where the developer has [some control](https://medium.com/@cdmunoz/working-easily-with-fcm-push-notifications-in-android-e1804c80f74) whether to show the notification or not, iOS does not provide that facility. A notification sent will always be shown. So, your `return` won't work.

One work around that you can do is send a [silent push notification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_updates_to_your_app_silently), process the data and if it fits your logic, then create a local notification and show that.

Comment: but the code you posted with the question does not show that purpose. It says that you do not want to show duplicate notifications. If you do not even want to send duplicate notification from the server, then the logic needs to be on server side.

Comment: sorry, i deleted my comment, didn't describe it well. 
the work around is perfect for this situation